# add incrementing class to images inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay I dont think anyone has covered this yet.

I have a div with x amount of images inside it. I need to add the class 00x to each image where the x starts at 1 and goes up everytime for each image. I have tried doing this with a for in statement however cant seem to make it work. I am using the jquery library so feel free to suggest jQuery related fixs. Here is my html:

```
<div id="fixed">
    <img src="/prodimages/Ad060-2.jpg" />
    <img src="/prodimages/Ad060-2.jpg" />
    <img src="/prodimages/Ad060-2.jpg" />
</div>
```

so I need it to select all images inside #fixed and then add the class 00 + i where i++ for each image. I need something like a php foreach. I dont really understand how for in works.

Please advise. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case the number of images should exceed 10, use something like:

```
function pad_number(num) {
   if(num < 10) return '00' + num;
   else if (num < 100) return '0' + num;
   return num;
}

jQuery('#fixed img').each(function(index, el) {
   jQuery(el).addClass(pad_number(index));
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I will give it a shot. I will actually have over 100 images so I guess I will need to do: else if (num > 99) return num;

Comment: If your number is greater than 99, it will fall through to the last line of the pad_number method so you should just get the original number back again.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
$("#fixed img").each(function(i) {
   $(this).addClass("00" + i);
};
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I was a little unclear on my requirments, the answer I have accepted actually does what I need although this does work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#fixed img").each(function(i){
  this.addClass($.strPad(i,3));
});

$.strPad = function(i,l,s) {
    var o = i.toString();
    if (!s) { s = '0'; }
    while (o.length < l) {
        o = s + o;
    }
    return o;
};
```

source padding function: http://stv.whtly.com/2009/02/27/simple-jquery-string-padding-function/

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Why does he need another function to add the extra zeros in front?

Comment: "and then add the class 00 + i where i++ for each image" He maybe need the additional zeros in other part of his page or css. This will work also without the padding function, but the question requested zeros ;)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, im afraid i was a little unclear on this point, the classes should go 001-009,010-099,100-999
The top answer has done the trick, but thats for the alternative. interesting to no!